# What do Ace Levels do?

Tags: 10000000

What do Ace Levels do?

I know you get them by resetting the game once you're done, and it makes the game harder.

But do scores increase as well, and therefore make it easier to get Steam Achievements?

Or if I knew where my saves are, I could back it up and test myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ace levels are basically just new game+. Everything is reset, gets a bit harder and you can through again.

As far as I know, there is no limit to the ace levels and it's nothing more than a skill challenge at how far you can go.

Scores do not increase.

In the sequel, "You Must Build A Boat", ace level 3 is required for an achievement and the dev said, ace levels would transfer between the two games, however I've no idea, whether that's actually true.

Comment: But, scores increase with Ace levels, yes or no?

Comment: No, more score would mean, you finish the game faster.

Comment: So, that means it'd be even harder to get achievements. Ah well.